# Java Swing, Further do-while Issue

Tags: java, swing, do-while, infinite

Hello again stack community,
    I am working on a program to graphically display prompts, stored in a 2D array, and their correct response counterparts - I start off by calling the creation of a Menu object:

```
    public static void main (String [] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() { new Menu(); } 
    });
}
```

Within Menu I define various buttons:

```
JButton chem3Button, chin1Button, mathstatButton//etc...
```

followed by an action listener that follow the addition of properties such as the the tooltip and such:

```
         mathstatButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent j) {
            new matstatMenu();
        }
     });
```

which in turn passes control to matstatMenu, which allows the selection of an area in Mathematics, which in this case is only one, the available:

```
         mathstatb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
            new SwingImplementation(2, 1);
        }});
```

Which sends Subject 2 (Math), and Subject Subset 1 (Descriptive Statistics) to SwingImplementation via the mathstatb1 button, to fly through this loop that copies the statistics array to oneRay:

```
        case 2:
        switch(unit){
        case 1: 
            oneRay = new String[Master.MathaRay_Part2.length][2];
           for(int i = 0; (Master.MathaRay_Part2.length) > i; i++){
               oneRay[i][0] = Master.MathaRay_Part2[i][0]; oneRay[i][1] = 

Master.MathaRay_Part2[i][1];} break;
        default: System.exit(0); break;
        } break;
```

and then fails to progress through this do-loop, which cycles infinitely despite the fact that the array Master.MathaRay_Part2 is full and by the above code should be fully copied.
Why is this do loop failing, or rather, never exiting?

```
    do{
        System.out.println("C");
        pick = random.nextInt(oneRay.length);
    }while((oneRay[pick][0]).isEmpty());
```

Please, I am just a swing-neophyte trying to create a program to help myself and peers in school, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I'd use i < Master.MathaRay_Part2.length, as it keeps i within the fail able range of the array, but that's me...

Comment: If element 0 of each element of oneRay were initially empty, there would be nothing happening to change that. I would check the state of oneRay on entry to the `do` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is - there isn't enough code here for me to figure it out; and I know nothing about the `Master.MathaRay_Part2` class. However, doing the following should help you, and would help me help you if you edit the results into your original post.

First, add the following function to your class that has the `do` loop:

```
private static final String toTwoDArrayString(Object[][] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    boolean first = true;
    for(Object[] row : arr) {
        if (!first) {
            // Requires Java 7. replace %n with either \n or \r\n for Java 6
            sb.append(String.format(",%n ")); 
        }
        first = false;
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
    sb.append(']');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Second, make sure that `Master.MathaRay_Part2.toString()` is implemented in a useful way, if it isn't already. In Eclipse, you can use `Right Click -> Source -> Generate toString()...`

Finally, immediately before the `do` loop, call:

```
System.out.println(toTwoDArrayString(onepick));
```